# Is there a way to reference the child of a WPF UI element by name?

Tags: .net, wpf

I've got a very simple app.xaml.cs that, when the app starts up, creates a new PrimeWindow, and makes it accessible to the outside.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static PrimeWindow AppPrimeWindow { get; set; }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        AppPrimeWindow = new PrimeWindow();
        AppPrimeWindow.Show();    
    }
}
```

The xaml for PrimeWindow looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.PrimeWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="500"
    xmlns:MyControls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <DockPanel Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MyControls:ContentArea x:Name="MyContentArea" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Being a complete WPF novice, I'm doubtless messing several things up, but the question of the moment is this: *how do I reference the content area in code elsewhere?*  I can easily get ahold of the DockPanel, via something like

```
DockPanel x = App.AppPrimeWindow.dockPanel1;
```

But digging any deeper doesn't seem easy to do.  I can get a UIElementCollection of the DockPanel's children, and I can get individual children by an integer index, but, from a maintainability standpoint, that's clearly not the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reference the children, passing the `UIElementCollection` around would do it. If you just wanted to access MyContentArea, there's nothing stopping you from doing the following:

```
MyControls.ContentArea = App.AppPrimeWindow.myContentArea;
```

If you need to dynamically see if theres a ContentArea within your DockPanel, the following would work:

```
DockPanel dock = App.AppPrimeWindow.dockPanel1;

for (int i = 0; i < dock.Children.Count; i++)
{
  if (dock.Children[i] is ContentArea) // Checking the type
  {
    ContentArea ca = (ContentArea)dock.Children[i];
    // logic here
    // return;/break; if you're only processing a single ContentArea
  }
}
```

Comment: All the answers are good for different reasons; however, this one highlights the easiest way to do this, and also explained something else to me at the same time.  So: acceptance.

Answer (score 4):

Very simply,

```
ContentArea contentArea = dockpanel1.FindName("MyContentArea") as ContentArea;
```

Comment: This is essentially what I was trying, and figuring I had to do, but didn't realize that FindName was what I was looking for...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
...
<DockPanel Name="dockPanel1" x:FieldModifier="Public" VerticalAlignment="Top">
...
```

This will make the `dockPanel1` field public, so it will be accessible from other classes

Note that it's not very good practice as it breaks encapsulation... You could also expose the `DockPanel` as a public property defined in your code-behind

Comment: Thanks!  Now I just need to figure out if I really want to break encapsulation here, or if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do (probably.)